# How to install xcfe on OpenBSD 5.9

Tags: openbsd

I tried following the [instructions](http://ribalinux.blogspot.se/2015/05/how-to-install-openbsd-57-plus-xfce.html) but nothing works. I get a msg that

"can't connect or login to host ftp.openbsd.org"

Why? It doesn't even get started. My internet connection works and I'm trying to install xcfe but it is not possible to install anything. Why must I reconfigure who whole operating systems just to install a window manager and why is it more difficult than research and development just to install something?

Comment: going to http://ftp.openbsd.org/ worked for me, but ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/ did not; it appears the instructions are referring to the FTP protocol; either the ftp service on ftp.openbsd.org is temporarily or permanently down.

Comment: because the openbsd devs are out to get you.  yes, you should take it personally, their every action is directed towards making your life difficult.  complaining about their persecution of you is exactly what this site was set up for.  no thanks necessary, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all OpenBSD mirrors support FTP—FTP is depreciated in favor of HTTP.  I recommend you visit the official OpenBSD site for more information—a list of mirrors is available at http://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html.

Comment: Great, it worked to change to ftp.eu.openbsd... and then it worked.